# Conditional rendering of React components without using ternary operators

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi currently have the following code React code:

```
  return (
    <Container>
      {booleanValueOne ? (
        <TrueComponent props={props} />
      ) : (
        [
          <DefaultComponentOne props={props} />,
          <DefaultComponentTwo props={props} />,
        ]
      )}
    </Container>
  );
```

So if `booleanValueOne` is true we return `<TrueComponent` and if not returning an array of DefaultComponents. This is straightforward.

But I since want to add a second boolean value: `booleanValueTwo` - and if it's true, return `TrueComponentTwo` & if neither of `booleanValueOne` or `booleanValueTwo` are true, returning the array of default components.

Can anyone share best practises for doing so?

I can't use a ternary as I have 3 possible outcomes.

Comment: Nested ternaries? Or just write a damn `if - else if - else` :)

Comment: Why not have `if return`? No need for `else`

Comment: @evolutionxbox Then you might need to duplicate the wrapper code in every return.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko oooo, what about a render function?

Comment: Yeah, might also work. `<Container>{(() => {})()}</Container>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have nested ternaries. Should be readable if properly aligned

```
const result = booleanValueOne ? (
  <TrueComponent props={props} />
) : booleanValueTwo ? (
  <TrueComponentTwo props={props} />
) : (
  [<DefaultComponentOne props={props} />, <DefaultComponentTwo props={props} />]
);


return (<Container>{result}</Container>)
```

Or you could use normal control flow `if - else if` to assign correct value to `result` variable.

```
let result = null;

if (booleanValueOne) {
  result = <TrueComponent props={props} />;
} else if (booleanValueTwo) {
  result = <TrueComponentTwo props={props} />;
} else {
  result = [
    <DefaultComponentOne props={props} />,
    <DefaultComponentTwo props={props} />,
  ];
}
```

Comment: @cts Glad I could help. Ternary is just an expression so you can have it anywhere you can put expression. Just be careful to not make it unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this template :

```js
return (
    <Container>
      {booleanValueOne && (
        <TrueComponent props={props} />
      )}
      {(!booleanValueOne && booleanValueTwo) && (
        <TrueComponentTwo props={props} />
      )}
      {(!booleanValueOne && !booleanValueTwo) && (
        [
          <DefaultComponentOne props={props} />,
          <DefaultComponentTwo props={props} />,
        ]
      )}
    </Container>
);
```